# How to display addition even if one of textboxes is empty?

Tags: c#, addition

I have this code:

```
private void adition()
{
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;

    if (Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out a)&& Int32.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out b)&& && Int32.TryParse(textbox3.Text, out c) )
    {
        resultLabel.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
    }

private void Result_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   adition();
}
```

How can I make when I press Result button to get result in resultLabel.Text  even if one of textboxes is empty.

it won`t addition and display result until I fill all the fields.

Comment: Because of the [`&&` operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2a723cdk.aspx), if the first TryParse is false, it won't bother checking the other two TextBoxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you want to achieve something like this:

```cs
private void addition()
{

    int a = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int c = 0;

    Int32.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out a);
    Int32.TryParse(textbox2.Text, out b);
    Int32.TryParse(textbox3.Text, out c);
    resultLabel.Text = (a + b + c).ToString();
}
```

Not parseable fields are defaulted to 0 in this case.

Comment: Possible counter example: `textbox1.Text == "bla-bla-bla"` you don't check `TryParse` return so the outcome will be `b + c`

Comment: This is exactly what enache vladd wanted to know. He wanted to add all legitimate entered values and ignore the unparseable ones if I got him right.